# Importing memcache from google.appengine.api without using dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine

According to the Google AppEngine documentation, one should import memcache like this:

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache
```

I'm using a virtualenv and I'm creating some scripts to test a library I created for AppEngine. I am not trying to test a website, I am trying to test a specific library that uses memcache. Evidently, without using `dev_appserver.py` I get an `ImportError: No module named google.appengine.api`.

I had a look at the [source](https://gist.github.com/1757540) of `dev_appserver.py` but first I'd like to know if there is a simpler solution that would not require rewriting PATH as Google does.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple solution, at the minimum you'll have to setup your Python paths.  That's all the dev_appserver wrapper you linked to does.  For testing code / libraries I usually write a simple wrapper that does basically the same thing as dev_appserver is doing.

In some cases you'll actually need to go a step further and initialize the stubs as well.  If you follow through the dev_appserver code, you'll be able to see how this is done.

Comment: Thanks! I found this very interesting article: http://blairconrad.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/automated-testing-using-app-engine-service-apis-and-a-memcaching-memoizer/

Comment: Cool, looks like a good resource!  I've got similar setup code I use.

Answer (score 2):

For testing purposes we always create a local checkout of the AppEngine library like this:

```
GAE_VERSION=1.6.2

resttest: dependencies lib/google_appengine/google/__init__.py
    sh -c "PYTHONPATH=lib/google_appengine/ python tests/resttest.py --hostname=$(TESTHOST) --credentials-user=$(CREDENTIALS_USER)"

lib/google_appengine/google/__init__.py:
    curl -s -O http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/google_appengine_$(GAE_VERSION).zip
    unzip -q google_appengine_$(GAE_VERSION).zip
    rm -Rf lib/google_appengine
    mv google_appengine lib/
    rm google_appengine_$(GAE_VERSION).zip

dependencies:
    git submodule update --init
```